# ionic 2 - Using Highchart in the Segment

Tags: ionic2, segment

I use HighChart library in the Segment, my segment have 2 tab DASHBOARD and NEW, my Chart in the DASHBOARD tab. First run: My Chart run, but i click to New tab and come back DASHBOARD tab => My chart not run ?
[sorry, i'm not good english]
-- My code html:

```
<div class="segment-chart">
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="pet">
        <ion-segment-button value="dashboard" (ionSelect)="selectedFriends()">
            DASHBOARD
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="new">
            NEW
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
</div>

<div [ngSwitch]="pet">
    <div class="chart" *ngSwitchCase="'dashboard'">
        <!--View Chart-->
        <div #chart>
            <chart type="StockChart" [options]="options"></chart>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul *ngSwitchCase="'new'" style="list-style-type:none" class="div-new-body">
        <li class="div-new-li" *ngFor="let new of lsNews">
            <div class="div-new-detail">
                <div class="div-new-title">
                    {{new.date}}
                </div>
                <div class="div-new-content">
                    {{new.title}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-new-nav">></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My code file ts:

```
export class ChartPage implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
private _chart: any;
lastData: any
lstData: any = []
pet : any
lsNews : any = []
opts : any;
@ViewChild('chart') public chartEl: ElementRef;
//chartOption: any

// Destroy Chart
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    console.log("OnDestroy run")
    var chart = this._chart
    chart.destroy();
}

// option Chart
ngAfterViewInit() {                    
    if (this.chartEl && this.chartEl.nativeElement) {
        this.opts.chart = {
            // type: 'area',
            renderTo: this.chartEl.nativeElement,   
              backgroundColor: {
        linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
        stops: [
            [0, '#3d4d64'],
            [1, '#3d4d64']
        ]         
    },
     height: '90%',
      spacingBottom: 15,
    spacingTop: 10,
    spacingLeft: 10,
    spacingRight: 10,   

        };
        console.log('chart create ss')
        this._chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(this.opts);         
    }
}

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public service: Service) {

    const me = this;

    this.pet= 'dashboard';
    setInterval(function () {
        if (me._chart) {

            me._chart['series'][0].addPoint([
                (new Date()).getTime(), // gia tri truc x
                //5// gia tri truc y
                me.getData()
            ],
                true,
                true);
        }
    }, 3000);

      this.opts = {           
        credits: {
               enabled: false
             },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,             
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: '#705f43' // color time
            }
        },
        lineColor: '#705f43' // 2 line cuoi mau trang                      
    },

          yAxis: {
        gridLineColor: '#705f43', //line gach ngang
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: '#fff'
            }
        },
        lineColor: '#ff0000',
        minorGridLineColor: '#ff0000',
        tickColor: '#fff',
        tickWidth: 1,
        title: {
            style: {
                color: '#ff0000'
            }
        }
    },
        navigator: {
                enabled: false
            },          
        rangeSelector: {

            buttons: [{
                count: 1,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '1M'
            }, {
                count: 5,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '5M'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
    inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 0,

        },

        series: [{              
            name: 'Random data',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -50; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push([
                        time + i * 1000,
                        Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                    ]);
                }
                return data;
            }()),
             zones: [{
                color: '#f8ad40'
    }]
        }]
    };     
    //end contructor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have not been able to resolve this issue, I had the same issue using ion-segment and I was able to resolve it when I replaced ngSwitch with the [hidden] property.

The problem is that the canvas only get rendered once. The canvas is also lost once you switch between your segments, the only solution is to hide you segment when switching between segments

Edit  your HTML code to the one below and you should be okay

```
    <div class="segment-chart">
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="pet">
        <ion-segment-button value="dashboard" (ionSelect)="selectedFriends()">
            DASHBOARD
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="new">
            NEW
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
</div>

<div >
    <div class="chart" [hidden] = "pet != 'dashboard'">
        <!--View Chart-->
        <div #chart>
            <chart type="StockChart" [options]="options"></chart>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul  [hidden] = "pet != 'new'" style="list-style-type:none" class="div-new-body">
        <li class="div-new-li" *ngFor="let new of lsNews">
            <div class="div-new-detail">
                <div class="div-new-title">
                    {{new.date}}
                </div>
                <div class="div-new-content">
                    {{new.title}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-new-nav">></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

That should solve the issue.